# Data being duplicated when the update function is triggered - Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a web app and trying to update data on Firebase. But when the update function is being triggered, data is being duplicated on the database. I want data to be updated only inside `voter/voterId`. I don't want the same data to be duplicated inside `voter/`. Here's my code:

```
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


var voterid, name, nic, mobile;

function Ready(){
    voterid = document.getElementById("voterid").value;
    name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    nic = document.getElementById("nic").value;
    mobile =  document.getElementById("mobile").value;
}

document.getElementById("register").onclick = function(){
    Ready();
    if (voterid != null){
    firebase.database().ref('voter/'+voterid).update({
        name : name,
        nic : nic,
        mobile :mobile
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Database Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `voterid` is an empty string, which you don't check for.

```
if (voterid != null && voterid.length > 0){
  firebase.database().ref('voter/'+voterid).update({
    name : name,
    nic : nic,
    mobile :mobile
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now the data isn't being duplicated. But now `mobile, name` and `nic` fields are not being updated. They have null values.

Comment: That seems like a different problem, so I recommend posting a new question for it. It also seems unrelated to Firebase: if you `console.log(name)` after calling `Ready()`, you expect it to log a value and it doesn't. Reducing the scope of the problem that way, increases the chances that someone can help.